# Position textbox within 2 pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting

I'm writing a document, where I want my figures to be automatically positioned within 2 pages (on the same or next page) from the place of the first reference at the bottom of a page, with text floating around it.

Currently, I'm placing a figure and a caption in a textbox, which I manually anchor to the first reference. In the layout settings of a textbox I can make it keep its position at the bottom of the same page with the anchor.

The problem is that pictures occupy about 50% of a page, which often forces Word to move them to the next page, and the anchor has to move with it, as well as all text after the anchor, which often leads to half-empty pages before the page with a picture. I included a picture to illustrate what I mean.

I would like to let Word know that pictures do not have to be on the same page as anchors, they can be on the next page, but I'm not aware of any way to do that. Any ideas?
[image: Illustration of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a Table instead of floating text boxes and that you place the image in that table as well. Allow the table rows to break across pages, which will stop the problem of half empty pages.

Table cells boarders, like text boxes, don't have to display or you can select certain ones to display and others to not as you wish.

Locking any object (Text Box, Shape, Picture, Table, etc) to a specific word is not possible. You can only lock an object to a Paragraph, Page, Margin and vertically to a Line. But locking an object to one of those does not help resolve your issue, which is keeping another object on the same page or at a minimum, the next page.

I have suggested a table because it will keep objects together and break across pages when necessary. If you use it, along with the Advanced Paragraph setting of "Keep With Next" applied to both the paragraph containing the referenced word, and the table that contains both the reference description and the image, I think that will accomplish what you want to happen.

Comment: Table positioning options are even more limited than those of a textbox. May I know how exactly do you suggest to set up table positioning so that it's anchored to a specific word and appears within 2 pages at the bottom of a page with text floating around it?

Comment: @DartLenin, I have added clarification to my answer.

Comment: You can anchor to a word if you surround it with style separators (ctrl+alt+enter). I tried your suggestion but when I select a position relative to a paragraph I have to specify exact distance from it. I want to position it at the bottom of a page, so hardcoding this distance is not what I want. Also, breaking across pages is not going to solve my problem because I always want to keep a picture and its title together. What I want to avoid is having to keep anchored word at the same page with figure, without losing anchor bond.